# Append removes last index in Python

Tags: python

My problem is that I tried to create a function that returns a list of all rotations of a list. When I write the "print" inside the function, it seems to work as intended but when I append it the last index is lost. Here's my code

```
    def rotation(list):
    l =[]
    for i in range(len(list)):
        m = list.pop()
        list = [m]+list
        print(list)
        l.append(list)
    return l
print(rotation(["a","b","c","d"]))
```

The output is

```
['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
[['d', 'a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'a'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Why are the values in "print" not going directly into the appended list, except for the last one (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) which works fine? Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: You used `pop()`, which is supposed to remove the last item

Comment: Maybe the problem is, that you change [list] while doing a for loop with it

Comment: Yes but I add it back in the beginning afterwards and in the "print" it doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: I don't really know how or why, perhaps it's sloppy coding but "l.append(list+[])" fixed the problem

Comment: BTW, you really shouldn't overwrite the builtin [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) by a variable with the same name.

Comment: If you do `l.append(list+[])` you add a new list to `l`. In your original code you added `list` and in the next loop you removed the last element from the same list. Then, with `list = [m]+list` you created a new list that is no longer referenced in `l`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python all mutable objects are passed by reference, this means that when you do  `l.append` you are actually appending a reference to `list`

then when you `pop` again from `list`, that same reference in `l` gets poped, I'll try to explain with the actual values after each line executes:

```py
l =[]
for i in range(len(list)):
```

at this point `l` is `[]` and `list` is `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

```py
m = list.pop()
```

`list` is `['a', 'b', 'c']` and m is now `'d'`

```py
list = [m]+list
print(list)
l.append(list)
```

`list` is now `['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']`, we print the value and we append it to `l` which is now `[['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']]`

we then start our second iteration:

```py
m = list.pop()
```

here two things happen, `list` is now `['d', 'a', 'b']`, so `l`, which contained a reference to `list` becomes `[['d', 'a', 'b']]`

```py
list = [m]+list
```

`list` now becomes a new list that's the combination of `[m]` and `list`, the reference is lost and now you are operating on a new list, thus leaving the list in `l` with only 3 items after the `pop`

Answer (score 1):

m = list.pop() -> this part shows last element and DELETES it.
If i were you I would try using something like this:

```
m = list[-1]
```

the [-1] returns last element

and then, if you need to use list without last element use this:

```
new_list = list[0:-1]
```

new_list equals "list "in the range of 0 up to last element (not including it)

Here is the website with the list of all the things you can do on list object in Python.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

Answer (score 1):

When you use pop, the value disappears from that list.

Instead, use the subscription [-1] if you want to get the last value of a list without removing altogether.

```
def rotation(lst):
    l =[]
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        l.append(lst)
        m = lst[-1]
        lst = [m]+lst[:-1]
    return l
print(rotation(["a","b","c","d"]))
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['d', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']]
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, `l.append(list)` adds a link to the list, not the value, and when you change it (list), then all links point to the changed list. At the end of the iteration, you added a list of 4 elements, at the beginning of the next you deleted the last one, and that’s 3-3-3-4. Use `list.copy()`, it is intended for such things.

```
def rotation(list):
    l = []
    for i in range(len(list)):
        m = list.pop()
        list = [m]+list  
        # Little tricks in single line: list[:0] = list.pop()
        l.append(list.copy())
    return l

print(rotation(["a","b","c","d"]))
```